# Perfect way to configure esapi to mitigate XSS SQLI {GET/POST data}

Tags: java, jax-rs, esapi

We have a jaxrs service, Unfortunately the raw query is executed,No prepared statement. We used ESAPI to mitigate XSS,SQLI.  Something like below:

```
private String mitigateSQLI(String value) {

        Encoder instance = ESAPI.encoder();
        Codec c = new MySQLCodec(MySQLCodec.Mode.ANSI);

        return instance.encodeForSQL(c, value);
    }

    private String mitigateXSS(String value) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        // Use the ESAPI library to avoid encoded attacks.
        value = ESAPI.encoder().canonicalize(value);

        // Avoid null characters
        value = value.replaceAll("\0", "");

        // Clean out HTML
        Document.OutputSettings outputSettings = new Document.OutputSettings();
        outputSettings.escapeMode(EscapeMode.xhtml);
        outputSettings.prettyPrint(false);
        value = Jsoup.clean(value, "", Whitelist.none(), outputSettings);

        return value;
    }
```

Along with the ESAPI.properties file with default configuration.

Still we are facing SQLI on certain scenarios, Knowing the queries are concatenated and formed.

Wanted to know if the best way/configuration to mitigate these things. Way can be the ESAPI properties or these ESAPI available methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run away to the alternatives. As quoted in bold in the [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

**Primary Defenses:**

- Option 1: Use of **Prepared Statements** (with Parameterized Queries)
- Option 2: Use of **Stored Procedures**
- Option 3: **Whitelist** Input Validation
- Option 4: **Escaping** All User Supplied Input

**Additional Defenses:**

- Also: Enforcing **Least Privilege**
- Also: Performing Whitelist Input Validation as a Secondary Defense

Configuring ESAPI.properties as per application requirement is important. When not using Prepared Statement, You must escape inputs on the server side. For Java , StringEscapeUtils from Apache does the job.

Comment: Your answer should be the accepted answer, and that's coming from one of the ESAPI co-leads.  ESAPI's SQL codecs (all of them) are a stopgap solution only.

Comment: I'd pretty much rather delete my answer because I didn't see yours, but it's up to you.  I think my answer is a good chorus to yours!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that the design intent for ESAPI's SQLi codecs was to provide emergency support in a post-compromise scenario to buy time for you to rewrite the vulnerable queries with a `PreparedStatement` or some equivalent.  OWASP makes no assurance because the peculiar language quirks present in the various RDBMS implementations aren't typically common knowledge.  It's not that ESAPI won't protect you at all--but it will never be as good as with a `PreparedStatement`.  I would expect only a partial mitigation.

I would also recommend against using Jsoup in lieu of `Validator.getValidSafeHTML()`.  Jsoup will attempt to "correct" invalid HTML, and that gets complicated extremely quickly in the contexts of input validation and safe HTML.

Comment: Thanks, Does ESAPI work for the POST request ? For example , JSON as the POST data.

Comment: @Manasi ESAPI validates input string whether its GET or POST. I am assuming that you must have created the HTTP interceptors to catch GET/POST data.

Comment: Get out of interceptors and/or servlent filters @Manasi, the security problem is NOT solvable at that level!